# GIMP - Something wrong with color?

Tags: gimp

So I was trying to color in some lines and I picked a red to do so. When I tried to pick a black, instead of color over the red, it colored around the red, but would not color on the red. I can color over the red with lighter colors, but can not with darker. Please help?

Comment: SOLVED Disable monitor or system color management ! Check your syslogs:: gimp.desktop[1028]: gimp_color_transform_new: using babl for 'HP' -> 'GIMP built-in sRGB'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the mode[1] of either the paint tool or the layer you are painting on. If it not `Normal` (for instance it could be in "Lighten only" mode) then unexpected things[2] can happen.

[1] Drop-down selector at the top of the Layers list for layers, or at the top of the Tool option dialog for paint tools

[2] if you don't know about layer/paint modes of course.

Comment: Ahhh that fixed it. I had the mode for the layer on normal, but the paintbrush mode was on luma. Thanks so much! <3